# Receiving json with list using nodejs e express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to receive a json with list of items in a nodejs code, but it doesn't works.

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    models.sequelize.transaction().then(transation => {
        let entity = req.body;
```

If req.body it's just an element, works perfectly well.

Comment: What is the value of  `req.body`? when it doesn't work, please give us more details.

Comment: req.body Is the content comming from post

Comment: Have you add this code ` app.use(bodyParser.json());` yet?

Comment: Thanks @zangw. You really help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `app.use(bodyParser.json());` to your code, make sure the `JSON` could be parsed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I needed use JSON.stringfy first, then JSON.parse.

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
models.sequelize.transaction().then(transation => {
    let entities = JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2);
    entities = JSON.parse( entities ); here
```

Probably it's not the best way, but works for me.